# AngularJS nested filter hiding elements without destined property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm using AngularJS on a project and I need to implement a select box with a filter to a nested property. My object (I have an array of those and I'm iterating through them via ng-repeat) has a structure similar to this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Example',
  groups: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Group 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Group 2' }
  ]
}
```

I need to filter the group ID of the elements, and after searching I've come up with two ways to do it:

1.

```
| filter: { $: { id: search.item_id } }
```

Which has these problems:

Apparently it searches for any nested properties named ID, so if I have more than one object inside my main object, with a property called ID too, it would add it to the filter. Example:

```
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'Example 2',
  groups: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Group 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Group 2' }
  ],
  categories: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Cat 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Cat 2' }
  ]
}
```

Filtering for ID 1 would select not only group with ID 1, but category with ID 1 too.

Also, with this method, even before setting the filter (search.item_id model is null), objects without groups are being filtered and not appearing in the list. These objects are like this:

```
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'Example 3',
  groups: []
}
```

and the other way is:

2.

```
| filter: { groups: [{ id: search.item_id }] }
```

In this case, the problem is that it simply doesn't work, it filters everything, leaving the list blank, no matter if it's set or which option is selected.

How can I make it work? I've been searching and couldn't find anything about this. Filtering nested properties is (or should be) a very basic thing.

---

**Update:**

So, *xtx* first solution kinda did it, but only if I use input text or number, but I need to use a select box (more specifically uib-dropdown, but working in a regular select is the next step). My select box is looking like this:

```
<select name="filter_classes_groups_test" ng-model="search.group_id">
  <option val="group.id" ng-repeat="group in classesGroups">{{ group.name }}</option>
</select>
```

When I interact with it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If creating a custom filter works for you, here is how you can do that:

```
app.filter('groupsFilter', function() {
  return function(input, groupId) {
    var out = [];

    if (!groupId || isNaN(parseInt(groupId))) {
      return input;
    }
    angular.forEach(input, function(item) {
      if (item.groups && angular.isArray(item.groups)) {
        angular.forEach(item.groups, function (group) {
          if (group.id === parseInt(groupId)) {
            out.push(item);
          }
        });
      }
    });
    return out;
  }
});
```

As you can see, the custom filter has name groupsFilter, and takes group id to search for as a parameter. The filter can be applied like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data | groupsFilter:search.item_id">
  ...
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Instead of creating a custom filter, you can just create a function that implements filtering logic, in scope like this:

```
$scope.groupsFilterLocal = function(value) {
  if (!$scope.search.item_id || isNaN(parseInt($scope.search.item_id))) {
    return true;
  }
  if (!value || !value.groups || !angular.isArray(value.groups)) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < value.groups.length; i++) {
    if (value.groups[i].id === parseInt($scope.search.item_id)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

and then apply it using build-in filter like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data | filter:groupsFilterLocal ">
  ...
</div>
```

Notice that in this case you can't pass the value to search for (search.item_id) into your function groupsFilterLocal like it is done for the custom filter groupsFilter above. So groupsFilterLocal has to access search.item_id directly

---

**UPDATE 2: How to create a select properly**

The reason why the filter is not applied when you pick a group in your dropdown, is in the way how you defined the select. Instead of the id of the selected group, search.group_id gets assigned group's name. 
Try defining the select like shown below:

```
<select name="filter_classes_groups_test" ng-model="search.item_id" ng-options="group.id as group.name for group in classesGroups">
    <option value="">-- Choose Group --</option>
</select>
```

To ensure that search.item_id gets id of the group that is selected (and not its name), try temporarily adding `{{ search.item_id }}` somewhere in your template.

Comment: Awesome, the first one did it and it seems like it's more clear than the second.
However, I've only managed to make it work using inputs like text or number, my objective is to use a select dropdown with the name of the group being visible, but the value being the ID of said group. But when I  use a select box to filter, nothing happens

Comment: I've added details about it in my question

Comment: Added explanation of why the filter is not applied when selecting an option from dropdown

Comment: Working, now I have some tweaks to do but it's not in my original question. The bounty is yours, but I have to wait 7 hours to give it to you. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great, glad I could help